# How many degrees (angle) to open the water at the curb?

Tags: water

If I want to turn the water on at the curb to I turn it 180? Or some other angle. It seems I've heard 90 degrees.

Comment: it is probably not your job to be turning that valve ... contact the city water department to do the valve turning ... if you mess with it and something breaks, then it may cost you lots

Comment: Good point. The city workers showed me how to do it when they turned it off but I didn't think to ask as the angle for when I turned it back on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

90 degrees if it's a ball valve.  ??? (certainly more than 360 degrees) if it's a gate valve.

You'll know it; there's a "stop" when you are at limits of travel.  Turning force will greatly increase.